# I closed nine questions regarding TheDAO hack

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, duplicates

As a moderator I don't want to intervene too much but today I had to close <del>eight</del> nine questions regarding TheDAO hack. I don't feel very comfortable with this action and therefore I would like to list these questions here and explain why they where closed and in case of dispute, please leave an answer or comment explaining why you disagree with a certain question being closed.

- [Who attacked "the DAO" on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6185/87) [closed], not constructive / leads to opinionated answers
- [How can we find "the DAO" attacker on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6187/87) [closed], not constructive / unclear about the specific scope of the question
- [How did they stop "the DAO" attack on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6189/87) [duplicate], of [TheDAO hack FAQ: How did the attack happen on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/87)
- [Does the recent attack to "the DAO" means end of it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6198/87) [duplicate], of [Is 'the DAO' dissolved?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6184/87)
- [In simple terms, how did the DAO get hacked and funds removed from it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6202/87) [duplicate], of [TheDAO hack FAQ: How did the attack happen on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6183/87)
- <del>[Writing secure Smart Contracts in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6204/87) [closed], too broad / not a good style to ask for resources or lists of things</del> reopened.
- [How was the recursion created that lead to theDAO hack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6210/87) [duplicate], of [What is a recursive calling vulnerability?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/87)
- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6222/87 [closed], not constructive / leads to opinionated answers. was also tempted to delete it because it lists names and asked for their opinion.
- [Is the 17 June 2016 operation legaly illigitimate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6243/87) [closed], primarily opinion-based / unclear what's being asked.

You can also leave a comment if you agree :-)

Comment: I support your moderation actions above. Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually also close a number of duplicates, but some of these are distinct and should be reopened imo.

[Writing secure Smart Contracts in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/writing-secure-smart-contracts-in-solidity) is a community wiki and I think it should be allowed and would be very helpful for the community; not all list/resource type of questions are bad.

[How was the recursion created that lead to theDAO hack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6210/87) is specifically about TheDAO.  There's a difference between "what is X", and "where is X in this program" or "how did X work in this program".

---

These ones can be discussed more and it may have been better for them to get more community votes about whether they should be closed.

[Who attacked "the DAO" on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/who-attacked-the-dao-on-17-june-2016) could be made a community wiki.  It is objective and fact based.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6222/87  is simply asking for "quotes" of team members.  It's not discussing the quotes.

Comment: I follow @eth on this points.

Comment: Okay, accepted. I reopened the secure smart contracts thingy. Please cast reopen votes on the others and let the community decide.

Answer (score 5):

"leads to an opinionate outcome" should not be a waiver for closing everything. It means two things: (1) there is no final objective outcome and answers could be only subjective, (2) there is a final outcome but the community is strongly opinionated and passionated about it, so I don't want to have the hassle as a moderator and OMG politics. Clearly only (1) is acceptable. so if this is your concern with question one, clearly it doesn't compute. Ok it's my question, but you get the point. Thanks.

Comment: I upvoted this and see your reopen request.  In the meantime though there's http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/how-did-the-dao-attack-happen-on-17-june-2016 which I posted a community wiki to which you also edited :)  Do you still think this should be reopened?  Are you interested to make it a community wiki?  Or do we merge the other one to yours?  Or just reopen yours but mark it dupe to the one that currently has the wiki?  Other ideas?

Comment: Do not yet get the plan with the comunity wiki, so this is a big pool where everything on the DAO attack goes? how can we start this with a huge citation from Martin Köppelmann? I added the citation marks because we can't just start from his original article and add things we like. This would initially be a illigitimate appropriation of the content of the original author. Do you agree? I'm rather confused how we can start a wiki from this. Wouldn't it be best writing your own content and start from it?

Comment: Good point, I updated the wiki so that people should feel free to keep it updated.  Did you want your question to be a wiki like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites ?  Your question looked like a wiki and not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: yes wiki is a good idea

Comment: ok, I think you'll want to keep it distinct from the other question/wiki